# Need to subtract each and every column value of two result sets in Java

Tags: java

I have two results sets. Each result set has same number of Columns and Column names are also same. I need to subtract each column values and display the difference in column and row fashion in an excel sheet.

```
Result Set1
RunId,      ScenarioId      runName         Price_M     Price_N  
2086269503      2523922677  Machine1-DBT10251       56      100.56

Result Set2
RunId       ScenarioId  runName         Price_M     Price_N
2086269521  2523928636  Machine2-DBT10251       47      45.68


In this , Data type of RunId, ScenarioId and Price_M is BigInt, Data type of runName is Varchar, Datatype of Price__N is Float

I am expecting an output like,

Output
RunId,      ScenarioId      runName         Price_M     Price_N
-18     -5959       No need to display  9       54.88
```

But my code gives output as without the line of code "System.out.print(Integer.valueOf(columnValue1) - Integer.valueOf(columnValue2) + "Difference" + resultSetMetaData1.getColumnName(i));"

2086269503 RunId,  2086269521 RunId,  2523922677 ScenarioPortfolioId,  2523928636 ScenarioPortfolioId,  Machine1-DBT10251 runName,  Machine1-DBT10251 runName

But with the above line of code  It throws me an exception like below

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2523922677" and the output is like,
2086269503 RunId,  2086269521 RunId -18 DifferenceRunId,  2523922677 ScenarioPortfolioId,  2523928636 ScenarioPortfolioId

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:DB server;username:password)
Statement st1 = conn.createStatement();
String sqlStr1 = " select * from tablename1 where runName='Machine1-DBT10251' order by
RunId,ScenarioPortfolioId"; 
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(sqlStr1);
Statement st2 = conn.createStatement();
String sqlStr2 = " select * from tablename1 where runName='Machine2-DBT10251' order by 
RunId,ScenarioPortfolioId";
ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sqlStr2);
while (rs1.next()) {
rs2.next();
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData1 = rs1.getMetaData();
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData2 = rs2.getMetaData()
int count = resultSetMetaData1.getColumnCount();           
//System.out.println("the count is" + count);
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
{
if (rs1.getObject(i)!= null && rs2.getObject(i) != null ) 
{
if (!rs1.getObject(i).equals(rs2.getObject(i))
{
if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
String columnValue1 = rs1.getInt(i);
String columnValue2 = rs2.getInt(i);
System.out.print(columnValue1 + " " + resultSetMetaData1.getColumnName(i));
System.out.print(",  ");
System.out.print(columnValue2 + " " + resultSetMetaData2.getColumnName(i));
System.out.println(columnValue1 + " is of type " + ((Object)columnValue1).getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.print("Sowmya" + resultSetMetaData1.getColumnName(i));
System.out.print(a-b + "Difference" + resultSetMetaData1.getColumnName(i));
System.out.print(Integer.valueOf(columnValue1) - Integer.valueOf(columnValue2) + "Difference" + 
resultSetMetaData1.getColumnName(i));           
}

}
                        
}
System.out.println("TRUE");
```

Please can anyone help me how to get My expected result?

Comment: I assume your code is current, have you tried Long.valueOf() instead of Integer.valueOf()

Comment: Java integers have a limit of just over 2 billion, being 32-bits. Use 64-bit `long`/`Long`. If the IDs are not truly numeric, use `String`.

Comment: Hi Timor / Basil , I have used Long.valueOf(). it worked fine till it encounters one date field "AsofDate" and throws exception like below  "Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from date to INTEGER is unsupported" . Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't select non-numeric columns? Hint: don't use `select *`

Comment: that is nice idea!! Thanks g00se! I want to convert My output to excel sheet ,My output as of now it is like below

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like someone else has removed that "nice idea" from my post

Comment: that is nice idea!! Thanks g00se! I want to convert My output to excel sheet ,My output as of now it is like below
2086269503 RunId, 2086269521 RunId -18 DifferenceRunId, 2523922677 ScenarioId, 2523928636 ScenarioId  DifferenceScenarioId

Expected in Excel like,
RunId RunId Difference RunId  Scenario id Scenario id Difference Scenario_Id 
2086269503 2086269521 -18 2523922677 2523928636 -5959
is it possible to do? if yes any idea will help me

Comment: You can [convert to csv](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/103-resultset-to-csv)